# ZendFramework Log Errors

Tags: php, zend-framework, logging

I'm trying to log all application errors easily. Does ZendFramework have a plugin that can do this, or can it do this natively?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to log errors in Zend Framework in my project at this stage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450842/what-is-the-best-way-to-log-errors-in-zend-framework-in-my-project-at-this-stage)

Comment: https://github.com/markushausammann/monitorix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend includes standard error handling plugin that redirects to ErrorController.
Here are 2 solutions:

1. Create [Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.standard.errorhandler) and register in bootstrap/controller
2. Create custom [PHP error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Answer (score 6):

Type in your configuration:

```
phpSettings.log_errors = 1
phpSettings.error_log = "/path_to_yours_application_logs/php.log"
```

This puts all error logs to php.log file. It's common approach in production environment.

Answer (score 1):

also you can use in your Controller

```
try{
} catch(Zend_Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage
    (or log errors in log file using Zend_Log) 
}
```

[Zend_Log](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.log.html)

[Zend_Exception](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.exception.html)

Answer (score 0):

To log all Error types (also PHP Fatal Error):

```
    register_shutdown_function( 'myErrorHandler' );
    function myErrorHandler() {
      $error = error_get_last();
      if( $error !== NULL) {
        getMyZendLogger->log("got error: ".$error["message"], Zend_Log::ERR);
      }
    }
```

See [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)

Zend_Log::registerErrorHandler() (Zend-FW 1.12) catch not all errors